# Unable to get the html body from a website using javascript from the browser console

Tags: javascript, browser, devtools

As far as I know, I've only had this issue come from wolframalpha.com e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5Bx%5E2++-+++16%5D

My goal is to get html using javascript. So opening the developer tools I wrote

```
document.body.innerHTML;
```

But get `Uh oh! Wolfram|Alpha doesn&amp;#x27;t run without JavaScript.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;div class=\"HHXp5 _2CYJA\"&gt;&lt;span&gt;Please enable JavaScript.`, as PART of the response and not the full contents of the webpage.

I didn't want to make assumptions about how the website is operating, so I am going off with the information I got back and framed my question this way. Javascript is clearly enabled and I am guessing some js functionality is redirected prior to the page loading.

I've tried this with the latest chrome incognito and safari.

Comment: Can you cross verify your site settings, you might have disabled javascript.Once I disabled javascript, I got the same response.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with FF77.

Comment: Thanks @SujithPatil, your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestions from the comments, the issue was resolved after reenabling javascript on my site settings.